# Is the question limit removed?

Tags: discussion, support, rate-limiting

I mean the 50Q per 50day, and 6Q per day limit.

I did some search on beta and found 50Q per month, though.

Comment: I don't have a reason to believe that it was removed. Why do you ask? (Namely, is there a particular case which caused you to think that the rate-limiting is no longer in effect?)

Comment: yes, it happened.

Comment: -facepalm- and would you care to illustrate that with a link or something? Personal anecdotes of "yes it happened" is not exactly useful if you want an explanation nor for us tracking down the problem.

Comment: Oh sorry for missing the details. Here is my 7th question with 24 hours: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/434519/test-for-daily-quota-on-6q-per-day-limit

Comment: That was your sixth (BTW, I deleted that post). In http://math.stackexchange.com/users/83036/wishingfish?tab=questions&sort=newest the "time" is the "last modified time", not the time of posting. [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433357/the-image-of-i-is-an-open-interval-and-maps-mathbbr-diffeomorphically-ont) was asked more than 24 hours ago, even though the most recent modification to it was 15 hours ago.

Comment: oh, ok, sorry about that..

Comment: No worries. I understand that the user interface can sometimes be confusing for new users.

Comment: So is it 50Q 50days or 1 month @WillieWong?

Comment: @Jellyfish: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2464/question-limit-per-month?rq=1 and http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4770/1543

Comment: Thanks @WillieWong, but I do remember I was alarmed that I can post only 50 questions every 50 day.

Comment: @Jellyfish: every 30 days. The OP probably made a typo. But if you find any official documentation that states every 50 days (for example a page in the help center or something like that), please point that out. That would be a bug and that would need to be fixed.

Comment: ok, will do so if I encountered it again. thank you.